# Insert selective columns to hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I want to insert selective columns to Hive and I am unable to do so. This is what I was trying via spark

```
val df2 = spark.sql("SELECT Device_Version,date, SUM(size) as size FROM table1 WHERE date='2019-06-13' GROUP BY date, Device_Version")

df2.createOrReplaceTempView("tempTable")

spark.sql("Insert into table2 PARTITION (date,ID) (Device_Version) SELECT Device_Version, date, '1' AS ID FROM tempTable")
```

My aim is to only insert selective fields to the table t2.  Table t2 has many other columns which I want to be padded as null. I can do the padding as long as I can specify the order. I do not want the order to be taken by default.
Something like ...

```
spark.sql("Insert into table2 PARTITION (date,cuboid_id) (Device_Version,OS) SELECT Device_Version, null as os, date, '10001' AS CUBOID_ID FROM tempTable")
```

Is there any way to do this ? Any options are welcome.

Comment: I believe when I run this directly on hive, it seems to work.

Comment: Hi, can you post your error?